# Display this tag cloud as a dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way I can display this Job Tag taxonomy cloud as a dropdown select box by editing the following code or by creating a new shortcode?

It's going into an ajax filter, so the dropdown needs to output the same links and values ect, however in a dropdown format instead of the tag cloud it currently produces.

```
/**
 * Job Tag cloud shortcode
 */
public function job_tag_cloud( $atts ) {
    ob_start();

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'smallest'                  => 16,
        'largest'                   => 16,
        'unit'                      => 'pt',
        'number'                    => 45,
        'format'                    => 'flat',
        'separator'                 => "\n",
        'orderby'                   => 'count',
        'order'                     => 'DESC',
        'exclude'                   => null,
        'include'                   => null,
        'link'                      => 'view',
        'taxonomy'                  => 'job_listing_tag',
        'echo'                      => false,
        'topic_count_text_callback' => array( $this, 'tag_cloud_text_callback' )
    ), $atts );

    $html = wp_tag_cloud( apply_filters( 'job_tag_cloud', $atts ) );

    if ( ! apply_filters( 'enable_job_tag_archives', get_option( 'job_manager_enable_tag_archive' ) ) ) {
        $html = str_replace( '</a>', '</span>', preg_replace( "/<a(.*)href='([^'']*)'(.*)>/", '<span$1$3>', $html ) );
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Do you want an input dropdown (select,option)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `format` attribute:

**Cloud returned as array but not displayed**

The variable $tag will contain the tag cloud for use in other PHP code

```
<?php $tag = wp_tag_cloud( 'format=array' ); ?>
```

(Source: [WP Manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud))

Consider to use `var_dump()` to the returned array in order to understand it structure, afterwards you can simply use a `foreach loop` and walk-through the tags and build a `dropdown`.

Comment: SO is basically for members with a bit of background in development so I can only share the main guideline and help with not working code. 1. `var_dump($tag);` will output the structure of that array. 2. Google `foreach loop php` and `php arrays` to learn more about arrays and loops.

Answer (score 0):

You need a foreach

**PHP**

```
foreach($atts as $row => $value) {
    echo"<option value='$value'>$row</option>";
}
```

The website that you linked use a jQuery dropdown with realtime search, you can do it with a jQuery plugin like this: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?S5JKymV5

If you use a jQuery to display your data in dropdown, you need a select/option input with a unique id (id="myDropdown") and assign it to the jQuery script.

**Example**
Assuming you use fuzzyDropdown plugin

*Html & PHP*

```
<div id="fuzzSearch">
    <div id="fuzzNameContainer">
      <span class="fuzzName"></span>
      <span class="fuzzArrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="fuzzDropdownContainer">
      <input type="text" value="" class="fuzzMagicBox" placeholder="search.." />
      <span class="fuzzSearchIcon"></span>
      <ul id="fuzzResults">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<select id="myDropdown">
    <?php foreach($atts as $row => $value) {
    echo"<option value='$value'>$row</option>";
}?>
</select>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#myDropdown').fuzzyDropdown({
    mainContainer: '#fuzzSearch',
    arrowUpClass: 'fuzzArrowUp',
    selectedClass: 'selected',
    enableBrowserDefaultScroll: true
});
```